# Accessing module variable in R

Tags: r, variables, module

Would you explain about variables in a module?

I defined a module like this :

```
    CMod <- function(){

        fld = 1:3
        getField <- function(){ fld }

        change <- function( ){
            fld <<- 10:13
            print( fld )
        }

        return (
            list( field=fld, change=change, getField=getField )
        )

    }
```

but the variable "fld" shows different value by access routine.

```
> myMod <- CMod()

> myMod$field
    [1] 1 2 3

> myMod$change( )
    [1] 10 11 12 13
> myMod$field
    [1] 1 2 3
> myMod$getField()
    [1] 10 11 12 13
```

When fld read Through the getField() function, 
it shows "10 11 12 13".
but When it read directly, it shows "1 2 3".

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

From `?'<<-'`,

"The operators <<- and ->> cause a search to be made through the environment
for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable
is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise 
assignment takes place in the global environment."

Your `change` function contains `<<-`, redefining `fld` throughout the function environment.

```
change <- function( ){
            fld <<- 10:13  ## 'fld' redefined
            print( fld )
        }
```

If you use `<-` instead, you'll see the difference.

```
> CMod <- function(){

      fld = 1:3
      getField <- function(){ fld }

      change <- function( ){
          fld <- 10:13
          print( fld )
      }

      return (
          list( field=fld, getField = getField, change=change)
      )

  }
> myMod <- CMod()
> myMod$field
## [1] 1 2 3
> myMod$change( )
## [1] 10 11 12 13
> myMod$field
## [1] 1 2 3
> myMod$getField()
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: The search is through the *parent* environment which may or may not be the global environment.

Comment: Hmmm... I realized What I thought wrong.


"list( field=fld.. " create new variable "field" that has same values with "fld"
and change() and getField() deals with the variable "fld", not "field."

is it right?

Comment: Seems that I still habit thinking like Java/C++.